# Excel VBA Filtering Issue

Tags: excel, excel-2007, autofilter, vba

Awesome Stackoverflow users,

I am having difficulty with something that seems simple enough to not cause this much trouble. I am trying to filter a given sheet based on a criteria. Here is the code:

```
Sub FilterWorksheet(sCriteria As String)
  'First, clear the filter
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyAwesomeSheet").AutoFilterMode = False

  'Then apply the filter for the Transfer_From_seg column
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyAwesomeSheet").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sCriteria
End Sub
```

For some reason, the last line where I actually apply the filter keeps giving me the following error message:

```
Runtime Error '448'

Named argument not found
```

Am I doing something really stupid with this?

Thanks!

Update:

So I found a solution. Here is what it looks like:

```
Sub FilterWorksheet(sCriteria As String)
  'First, clear the filter
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyAwesomeSheet").AutoFilterMode = False

  'Then apply the filter for the Transfer_From_seg column
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyAwesomeSheet").Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sCriteria
End Sub
```

I am not quite sure why this works & the previous one does not so if someone can explain it to me, that would be wonderful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Range that you want to filter. For example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyAwesomeSheet").Range("B3:C11").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=sCriteria
```

[Autofilter Method in the Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I just found the solution.